# Android socket.io encoding

Tags: android, ios, node.js, nginx, websocket

I use node.js + socket.io + nginx proxy http 1.1 for server side.

I added in my gradle file

```
compile 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.6.2'
compile('io.socket:engine.io-client:0.6.2') {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

I get bad encoding in android application.

```
{"date":"2015-12-12T21:00:00.000Z","text":"13 Ð´ÐµÐºÐ°Ð±ÑÑ 2015 ÐÐ¾ÑÐºÑÐµÑÐµÐ½ÑÐµ \r\n 3-Ð¹ Ð»ÑÐ½Ð½ÑÐ¹ Ð´ÐµÐ½Ñ Ð Ð°ÑÑÑÑÐ°Ñ Ð»ÑÐ½Ð° \r\n Ð¡Ð¸Ð¼Ð²Ð¾Ð» Ð´Ð½Ñ: ÐÐµÐ¾Ð¿Ð°ÑÐ´ \r\n Ð½Ð°ÑÐ¸Ð½Ð°ÐµÑÑÑ Ð² 10:00 \r\n ÐÐµÐ½Ñ Ð²Ð¾Ð¸Ð½Ð° Ð¸ Ð¿Ð¾Ð´Ð²Ð¸Ð³Ð°. \r\n ÐÑÐ½Ð° Ð² ÐÐ¾Ð·ÐµÑÐ¾Ð³Ðµ \r\n Ð¥Ð¾ÑÐ¾ÑÐ¾ ÑÐ´Ð°ÐµÑÑÑ Ð¿Ð»Ð°Ð½Ð¸ÑÐ¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¸ Ð½Ð°ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¾ Ð²Ð°Ð¶Ð½ÑÑ Ð´ÐµÐ». \r\n"}
```

iOS application work fine.

It seemes like Java wrong detects encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated socket.io for node.js and application work :)
I didn't think that problem in server because ios app work.